# Haskell about handling lists of list without any import

Tags: haskell

I am a totally new learner for Haskell:

Target: For a given lists of list: `[[7,3],[8,5],[7,2]]`,
Output a expand list: `[7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,7]`

Tasks: Writing two function: expand and scan to obtain the target

Process: I wrote expand function and now doing the scan function

```
main= print(scanD [[7,3],[8,5],[7,2]]) 

expanding :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
expanding y (n:ns)
  | (n>0) = y:expanding y (n-1:ns)
  | otherwise = []

expand :: [Int] -> [Int]
expand (x:xs) = expanding x xs

scanD :: [[Int]]->[Int]
scanD [[]] = []
scanD [x:xs] = expand x : scanD xs
```

I am struggling on scan part since I cannot deal with lists of list.
Please help!

My question is scanD not works as expected for recursively look for each sub list and apply the expand for each of them. How should I correct my code to become workable.

Comment: I find the type signature for this rather odd, I would expect a list of 2-tuples.

Comment: And once again, you write `[x:xs]`, where it should be `(x:xs)`, somehow, every other day, people make this mistake :(

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have tried to use (x:xs) instead, however, it still having an error

Comment: My question is scanD not works as expected for recursively look for each sub list and apply the expand for each of them. How should I correct my code to become workable.

Comment: What does "I cannot deal with lists of list" mean? If you got a compilation error, what did it say? What part of the error (if any) do you not understand? All this would be useful in your question.

Comment: Hint: Write a function that turns `[7,3]` into `[7,7,7]`, then use [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap).

Comment: @T.Tony: yes, there is still an error, since your first pattern is `[[]]` wich is *not* an empty list, but a list containing one element: the empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problems with `scanD`

There are three errors with `scanD` here:

1. your basecase uses the `[[]]` pattern, but this is *not* an empty list, but a singleton list (a list with one element): the empty list;
2. your second pattern uses as pattern `[x:xs]`, which is short for `[(x:xs)]`, so here you have again a singleton list, where the list is non-empty; and
3. the return type of `expand` is an `[Int]`, so we again build a list of lists.

We can fix those errors by writing:

```
scanD :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
scanD [] = []
scanD (x:xs) = expand x ++ scanD xs
```

So here we use `[]` as basecase, `(x:xs)` as inductive case, and we use `(++)` to concatenate the results of `expand` together.

## `concatMap`

Nevertheless can make it more elegant: what we see here is a typical `map` operation where we later concatenate the results together. We can use [**`concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) for this:

```
scanD :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
scanD = concatMap expand
```

## Improving types

The types you use are however rather odd, do not provide much guarantees, and make the function more restrictive than necessary. A list can not give any guarantees about the length. As a result a user could call your `scanD` function with a list containing the empty list, a list with 3 elements, etc. In those cases your `expand` function will not be able to handle it properly. One of the reasons why programmers use types is to ensure at compile time that functions obtain parameters that are elements of a specific domain. Although types are sometimes too "*coarse*" to capture the set of allowed variables (and furthermore it would sometimes be impossible to prove that the output is always an element of such types, usually by writing a signature, you aim to restrictions to what a function can handle as possible. In your case your function does *not* hint that it takes a list of 2-item lists.

Furthermore your function is rather restrictive: what if we wanted to `scanD` characters instead of `Int`s. Since you use a list, all elements in the list need to have the same type.

A better type to encapsulate this, would be a list of 2-tuples: `[(a, Int)]` for example. In that case we can write it as:

```
scanD :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
scanD = concatMap (uncurry (flip replicate))
```

we thus do not need to implement functions like `expand` and `expanding` anymore.

We can then call it like:

```
Prelude> scanD [(7,3),(8,5),(7,2)]
[7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,7,7]
```

But we can perform string processing as well:

```
Prelude> scanD [('i',1),('a',4),('t',2), ('f', 5)]
"iaaaattfffff"
```

In recent versions of `Data.List` module, `concatMap` has a more generic type signature, such that we can work with any `Foldable` type:

```
scanD :: Foldable t => t (a, Int) -> [a]
scanD = concatMap (uncurry (flip replicate))
```

Comment: May I ask you one more question? For the reverse one. [777888877] to [[7,3],[8,4],[7,7]]

Comment: @T.Tony: feel free

Comment: Can you see my coding from the above link?

Comment: The count is to count for the number of first consecutive number while the shrink is to remove all the first consecutive number

Comment: @T.Tony: here you need to use a colon, since you are constructing a list of lists, so `scanC (x:xs) = [x, count (x:xs)] : ...`. But there are still other errors, like non-exhaustive patterns, and the code is not very "Haskellish".

Comment: @T.Tony: a hint is to turn on `-Wall` and look at the warnings, Haskell can detect non-exhaustive patterns in your own functions. Furthermore it is advisable not to use functions like `tail`, `head`, etc. since those are non-exhaustive.

Comment: Oh, I got when should I use colon and when should I use ++ now.

Comment: @T.Tony: or you wrap the first element in a list, but that would only result in more inefficiency.

Comment: Can you explain more what non-exhaustive means?

Comment: @T.Tony: if you have different constructors (for example a list has two constructors `[]` and `(:)`), then it checks if all the possible constructors as parameters are covered. Since in your function of `count`, you only define the case for `(x:xs)`, the `[]` data constructor is not handled.

Comment: In Haskell (i.e. count :: [Int] -> Int) <----- This line is act like a constructor?

Comment: @T.Tony: no a constructor is define at the `data` (and `newtype`) level, you can not define extra ones (see https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor#Data_constructor)

Comment: Then should I rewrite the count function?

Comment: @T.Tony: yes, since now for instance it does not handle the empty list case (nor does `counting`, and `shrink` do this). Usually it is better to implement *total* functions: functions that work on *all* possible input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to process lists with a number to represent repetitions then the list must be all numeric. This list compression can be easily modified to handle tuples and a tuple version follows the list version.

```
ls = [[7,3],[8,5],[7,2]]]

[ [a|x<-[1..b]] | (a:b:c)<-ls]
```

The tuple version must have all one type of first element because a list is produced

```
tp = [('a',3),('b',5),('b',2)]

[ [a|x<-[1..b]] | (a,b)<- tp]
```